# Facebook Webhooks. How to create an event that will work on like and unlike?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to create an event that will work on like and unlike?,

when I create a webhook

> object = page callback_url = ”example.com" fields = feed verify_token =
>   hub_verify_token

verification `callback_url` passes and the answer is tapped

> { “success”: true }

But after like or unlike on `callback_url` nothing is sent.

The events that I have used before :
edge.create and edge.remove.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/83bI7.png

Help please!

Comment: I added a webhook in the app console for Page and field feed. I liked my own page and got this in my callback `[entry:[[changes:[[field:feed, value:[item:like, verb:add]]], id:123456789 time:1516354586]], object:page]`

Comment: However I didn't get a callback for unliking the page and I don't see which user it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to the problem:

Details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Code example in the JavaScript SDK:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/subscribed_apps",
    'POST',
    {
        "object":"page",
        "callback_url":"https://example.com/callback",
        "fields":"likes",
        "verify_token":"my_token_code",
        "access_token" : "you_access_token"
    }
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

but unlike for the page does not work (((

what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of all webhook fields in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/

There is no specific webhook about likes/unlikes. According to this article, it should be possible though: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

The feed hook may only deliver likes to posts:

> Describes nearly all changes to a page's feed, such as posts, shares,
>   likes, etc. The values received depend on the types of changes made to
>   the page's feed.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Comment: edge.create and edge.remove JS SDK Events: These Events will no longer be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

Comment: oh, interesting, i did not know about that, thank you! in that case, i will update my answer.

Comment: In the sense of ?

Comment: because it is not 100% clear in the docs if the page fans/likes should come with the feed hook.

Comment: I agree with you!